# Loading content into a div with jQuery.load(), how can I make new images fade in on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to achieve the following: I have a div on which I use the load() method to fetch new HTML content.

```
 $('#mydiv').load('/newcontent.html');
```

This new HTML also contains images, and I would like those images to be faded in once loaded.

First I tried using a callback function with the load() method, but this function is triggered as soon as the HTML is fetched, but before the browser has loaded all the new images.

Then I tried applying an on('load') event on all the newly fetched images, but this does not work at all.

```
$('#mydiv').load('/newcontent.html', function() { 
    $('#mydiv img').css('visibility','hidden').on('load', function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
});
```

The "visibility: hidden" works fine, so that my new HTML content is loaded into #mydiv, and all images are set to invisible. But the fading in does not work. The event I'm trying to bind here does in fact trigger as soon as the new HTML is loaded (which does not make any sense to me), but not when the individual images are loaded.

How can I solve this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeIn() and fadeOut() out jQuery. And if you want to do on load then use the event for that.